# Matlab: Classes and parfor loops

Tags: matlab, class, parfor

I have data which I want to analyse by using functions which I defined in classes. Each data set uses the same classes. Since I have independent tasks I wanted to use `parfor` to make it faster. Unfortunately I don't see any speed-up when using `parfor`. Since the code is very large I can not simply provide a minimum working example. I spend already several hours trying it.

`data(k)` is a struct containing doubles, cells and char

```
N = 100;
par_WT = linspace(0,1,10);
par_TT = 2;
for j=1:length(par_WT)
    my_WT = par_WT(j);
    my_TT = 2;
        parfor k = 1:N
            myData = data(k); 
            myOutput(k) = myData.myAlgo(my_TT, my_WT);
        end     
end

%% Work with myOutput...
```

`myAlgo`calls functions which call other classes with functions. If I use `parfor` instead of `for`, there in no difference in speed. But why? These are all independent tasks.

I would be very grateful if someone can give me a hint how I can make this work, or for any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In general 'profile' function in Matlab gives you an insight of how much time your (sub)functions consume.

It is confusing that data(k) is claimed as a struct while data(k).myAlgo(argin) looks like a method in a class.

Comment: Maybe `data(k)` is not of type struct. I am not really familiar with Matlab. But `data` contains doubles, cells and char.